# Calling AppSync Mutation from Lambda with Golang

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-lambda, aws-appsync

I'm trying to invoke a mutation from lambda (specifically using golang). I used `AWS_IAM` as the authentication method of my AppSync API. I also give `appsync:GraphQL` permission to my lambda.

However, after looking at the docs here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/appsync/

I can't find any documentation on how to invoke the appsync from the library. Can anyone point me to the right direction here?

P.S. I don't want to query or subscribe or anything else from lambda. It's just a mutation

Thanks!

------**UPDATE**-------

Thanks to @thomasmichaelwallace for informing me to use https://godoc.org/github.com/machinebox/graphql

Now the problem is how can I sign the request from that package using aws v4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a way of using plain `http.Request` and AWS v4 signing. (Thanks to @thomasmichaelwallace for pointing this method out)

```
client := new(http.Client)
// construct the query
query := AppSyncPublish{
    Query: `
        mutation ($userid: ID!) {
            publishMessage(
                userid: $userid
            ){
                userid
            }
        }
    `,
    Variables: PublishInput{
        UserID:     "wow",
    },
}
b, err := json.Marshal(&query)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}

// construct the request object
req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", os.Getenv("APPSYNC_URL"), bytes.NewReader(b))
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json")

// get aws credential
config := aws.Config{
    Region: aws.String(os.Getenv("AWS_REGION")),
}
sess := session.Must(session.NewSession(&config))


//sign the request
signer := v4.NewSigner(sess.Config.Credentials)
signer.Sign(req, bytes.NewReader(b), "appsync", "ap-southeast-1", time.Now())

//FIRE!!
response, _ := client.Do(req)

//print the response
buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
buf.ReadFrom(response.Body)
newStr := buf.String()

fmt.Printf(newStr)
```

Comment: Its work like a charm bro, thanks for saving my day. I used OpenID Connect that associated with Firebase Token, then I just set Issuer URL link to my Firebase app without using aws v4 signer

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that that API/library is designed to help you create/update app-sync instances.

If you want to actually invoke them then you need to POST to the GraphQL endpoint.

The easiest way for testing is to sign-in to the AWS AppSync Console, press the 'Queries' button in the sidebar and then enter and run your mutation.

I'm not great with go, but from what I can see there are client libraries for GraphQL in golang (e.g. https://godoc.org/github.com/machinebox/graphql).

If you are using IAM then you'll need to sign your request with a v4 signature (see this article for details: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signing_aws_api_requests.html)

Comment: Just to add to this, you can either do a GET or POST to your AppSync GraphQL endpoint from Lambda and you will need to sigv4 sign your requests as the answer above mentions. The go client you mention is the control plane client for Go for most AWS services (for AppSync this provides the CRUD operations for your AppSync entities).

Comment: can you provide an example how to sign the request from https://godoc.org/github.com/machinebox/graphql? I've been trying without any success

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the right way (http request instead of using aws lib)! I found a way using a plain http request (not elegant, though). If you want your answer to be accepted (or not.. it's up to you) please provide an example of how to use those lib so people can directly see your answer and not mine :)

Comment: I took a look (as I said, go is not a language I know too well-) and it seems because you have to know the body to sign, and you have to sign ahead of making the request, you can't use that library and have to do the forming yourself.

Comment: yeah I also realized that you have to include the body. I took a look at other graphql libraries and it seems it's also following the same pattern (you don't get to see the body). But thanks a lot! I know where to go from now :) I'm in the process of creating a library specifically for appsync (it's for internal use only). I'll update this question if I found another library that can be used for this!

Answer (score 0):

Update for the sdk v2:

```golang
func SignRequest(ctx context.Context, cfg aws.Config, req *http.Request, body []byte) error {
    signer := v4.NewSigner()

    hash := sha256.Sum256(body)

    cred, err := cfg.Credentials.Retrieve(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return signer.SignHTTP(ctx, cred, req, hex.EncodeToString(hash[:]), "appsync", cfg.Region, time.Now())
}
```

There is also a non-official client now:
https://github.com/sony/appsync-client-go